# Are languages losing features like honorifics due to code mixing with English?

Tags: english

This question is not the exact same as [this question here,](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/3004/correlation-between-politeness-of-a-culture-and-its-languages). Here, I want to ask if code mixing (if that's the right term) is affecting languages which are in contact with English.

E.g. Hindi is losing the honorific *ji* and that has (probably) happened after the contact with English.

Has this happened with other languages too?

Comment: I am not convinced that grammatical loans are at all common. Languages borrow lexical items; other features are usually due to their internal development, or extra-linguistic issues. In this case, "contact with English" comes together with contact with capitalism, and associated simplification of class relations. I would posit that the possibilities are, in decreasing order. 1. the loss of honorifics is due to an internal process of degrammaticalisation; 2. the loss is due to society in the background becoming less hierarchical; 3. The loss is due to English influence.

Comment: 1 No , 2 definitely not 3 Yes, that's what my exact question is, does this influence applies to other languages as well? (Well, to _convince_ you, https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/W14-3914 this is a paper on _basically lexical but, also has a few borrowed **grammatical constructs**_ examples of code-mixing, which I have been through a lot of times and _I know_ what it is like. The fact that I cannot give more examples off hand and can explain the phenomenon, but nonetheless observe it, made me ask the question.)

Comment: Is it possible there's just regression to the mean?  I don't know Indic, but in Europe and the Mediterranean *tu* was normal ca 2000 years ago, the *T-V* distinction started in courts half a millennium later, really became the continental norm 1000 to 500 years ago, but never really prevailed in some village dialects between people of the same social class.

Comment: @A.M.Bittlingmayer I am still looking that up, don't know about T-V distinction yet :) . Am a 12th grader now (we don't have linguistics as a subject till 12th, this is all out of my hobby)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite sure about this, but I would like to point out on a side note that English took some of its honorifics from France. Mr. is basically Monsieur and Mrs., Maistresse (*mistress*). So if you just want examples of mixed cultural honorifics, the English language itself is a good example of this.

Comment: This is interesting fact Molly, but no i was not asking about : _So if you just want examples of mixed cultural honorifics..._ is not what I was asking for. What I am asking though is : a) since English doesn't have _a good_ system of honorifics (_Mr. and Mrs._ are universal and as you pointed out, there are borrowed) b) and since Hindi does have _a better_ system of honorifics (if X > Y , Y would call X as X _ji_ and many more) c) and since Hindi has undergone significant code-mixing with English in India d) and lastly Hindi's honorifics are losing ground now; is (d) a result of (c) ?

Comment: I'm looking up examples right now, but here's one I've got so far: the Hindi-Persian mixing word for "uncle" is cacaa, and the Hindi-English mixing word is ankal. Apparently, one could either say "cacaa jaan" or ankal jii" (which uses the jaan/jii example you talked about), but not "cacaa jii" or "ankal jaan".

Comment: In this study, the opposite of what you're asking about seems to have happened: In all three extracts, every family member uses Korean words instead of English when calling, or addressing each other. [...] When the English-dominant son calls his daddy or mommy, he shifts to Korean each time he specifically calls A-p ah (Daddy) and Um-ma (Mommy) from his primary language. When calling his sister, he [...] does not follow the American way of calling each other by name within the same generation.

Comment: The sources, respectively: https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&lr=&id=NhW7IkefMbcC&oi=fnd&pg=PA336&dq=code-mixing+honorifics&ots=BeIzGV8mWZ&sig=rIQ8FhEjFzHwL92j821St95rp88#v=onepage&q=honorific&f=false
http://www.polydromo.gr/pdf/Epistimoniko/ekpaideysh_goneis_/HaesookHanChung_CodeSwitchingInFamily.pdf
I feel that last one is useful even though it comes to a different conclusion because, to understand a phenomenon, it's always important to study cases where that situation did not turn out as expected.  
Hope some of this helps!

Comment: Woah you have done quite a lot of research, for your Persian and Hindi examples I am sorry I didn't mention it earlier I am an Indian myself. _cacca jii_ is perfectly accepted as it was the original form (i.e. before the mising happened) as for _ankal jaan_ I am not sure but it is spoken quite often. _cacaa jii_ is accepted in your source as well

Comment: Molly, I did not mean to say that code-mixing resulted in complete destruction of the honorifics, but initially (from 1980 onwards) it did have a slightly different effect, that is, English **nouns** were mixed with Hindi ones. Thus mummy jii, uncle jii, daddy jii, aunty jii etc. As a rule of thumb, when there is only mixing of nouns in two languages it does not effect it's grammar. What I am asking about here is the _**diminishing**_ use of a _grammatical construct_ (honorifics) which exist (like above examples), but are **now** _not_ preferred over mummy , aunty etc. (i.e. without _jii_)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67167/discussion-between-wiccankarnak-and-molly-taylor).